# How to convert int to enum value?

Tags: c#, class

Here's my code thats throwing an error saying `Cannot convert type "int" to Cards.Suits` and
`Cannot convert type "int" to Cards.Rank`

```
private Card[] cards;
public Deck()
{
    cards = new Card[52];
    for (int suitVal = 0; suitVal < 4; suitVal++)
    {
        for (int rankVal = 0; rankVal < 14; rankVal++)
        {
            cards[suitVal * 13 + rankVal - 1] = new Card((Suits)suitVal, (Rank)rankVal);
        }
     }
}
```

the cards constructor is

```
public readonly Suits suit;
public readonly Rank rank;
public Card(Suits newSuit, Rank newRank)
{
    suit = newSuit;
    rank = newRank;
}
```

Now the Suits enum and Rank enum are as a regular deck of cards starting at ACE = 1 so on and suits are DIAMONDS, CLUBS, HEARTS, SPADES. 
Can anyone tell me why im getting the above error. The following code was taking from a book. 
Thanks!

*EDIT

```
    public enum ranks
    {
        ACE = 1,
        TWO,
        THREE,
        FOUR,
        FIVE,
        SIX,
        SEVEN,
        EIGHT,
        NINE,
        TEN,
        JACK,
        QUEEN,
        KING,
    }

    public enum Suit
    {
        DIAMOND,
        CLUB,
        HEART,
        SPADE,
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the definition for `Suits` and `Rank`?

Comment: Not a duplicate as that method is used and still returns an error

Comment: You're using `(Suits)suitVal` but the enum you posted is actually named `Suit`.

Comment: Your code defines enums `ranks` and `Suit`, but attempts to cast to types `Rank` and `Suits`. Make sure all of your type names match up.

Comment: Nope that does not work
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Suit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user2434321 there are quite a few mistakes in your code. See my answer below

Comment: when you run the above code,at first it is going to throw **ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException**..Change the initial value of the loops..

Comment: Solved by using Suits.Suit as it is a seperate class. Although my question now is how can i make it so i just use Suit to explicitly cast?

Comment: @user2434321 i have updated and verified my answer and it is working. you can use that

Answer (score 2):

According to your enum declarations, Suit is in the [0..3] range, while ranks is in the [1..13] range (pay attention, that ranks is not zero based), so the inner for loop should be corrected:

```
  for (int rankVal = 0; rankVal < 13; rankVal++) // <- 14 changed for 13: [0..13] has the same length as [1..14] 
  { 
    cards[suitVal * 13 + rankVal] = new Card((Suits)suitVal, (Rank)(rankVal + 1)); // <- removed -1 from index; add 1 to rankVal, we need [1..14], not [0..13]
    ...
```

Comment: -1 because the above code will throw an error when both suitval and ranval are 0. which will evaluate this  cards[suitVal * 13 + rankVal - 1] to cards[- 1]. Hence index out of range.

Comment: @Ehsan Ullah: Thank you, I've corrected index within cards[…]

Answer (score 1):

change your line in for like this

```
 cards[suitVal * 13 + rankVal] = new Card(((Suit)suitVal), ((ranks)rankVal));
```

and as your class is taking enums in constructor so change it like this

```
public readonly Suit suit;
public readonly ranks rank;
public Card(Suit newSuit, ranks newRank)
{
    suit = newSuit;
    rank = newRank;
}
```

Comment: Intellisense is still directing me to using public readonly Suits suit; as oppsed to your answer. I should mention this is a class library.

Comment: i have updated Suits suit to Suit suit; You are passing enumeration as parameter which is Suit (in the code you gave above). not Suits.

Comment: This does not work when i had to do it it was Suits.Suit and Ranks.rank

Comment: @user2434321 please post your entire code. What is Suits? is it a class? what is Ranks? we cannot keep guessing

Answer (score 0):

I will see it will get other error "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

When suitVal = 0 and rankVal = 0, cards[suitVal * 13 + rankVal - 1] =-1 which is outside array index.

Answer (score 0):

This is running well 
but correct this

```
    for (int suitVal = 0; suitVal < 4; suitVal++)
    {
        for (int rankVal = 0; rankVal < 14; rankVal++)
        {
            cards[suitVal * 13 + rankVal - 1] = new Card((Suit)suitVal, (Rank)rankVal);
        }
    }
```

Here

> in cards[suitVal * 13 + rankVal - 1]

```
[Loop 1:]
suitVal =0
rankVal=0
```

> [suitVal * 13 + rankVal - 1]= [0*13+0-1]= [-1] ! oops!

**and in your prgm:**

```
public readonly Suit  suit; //not Suits
public readonly ranks rank; //not Rank
```